# What hook for immediately after user is logged in?

Tags: hook, sessions

I'm trying to find what hook there is for immediately after the user logged in?

I've been looking at sessions_start and sessions_end but I'm not sure how exactly they work and nothing seems to be working the way I want it to, the docs arent the clearest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[member_member_login_start](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_auth/index.html#member-member-login-start) is what you're looking for

Comment: I decided to code it in a different way but I wanted a hook that would log them in first, then activate the hook. With member_member_login_start the user isn't logged in when the hook is activated. Thanks for your help though, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to do?

This may help. Download plugin [ress](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ress) and look at source code.

Edit: no, my mistake session_start is wrong hook. Sorry

Another suggestion, point return params of all login pages to an empty template where you run a plugin to test for T&C = done. If so, redirect here. If not, redirect there.

You can also use group_ids to redirect.

```
{exp:member:login_form return="template_group/my_login_redirect_template"}
```

For example

```
{if logged_in}
    {exp:my_login_plugin}
            {redirect='pages/terms_conditions'}
    {/exp:my_login_plugin}
{/if}
```

OR

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{group_id}" parse="inward"}

{case value="9"}
    {redirect='pages/terms_conditions'}
{/case}

{case value="6"}
    {redirect='template_name/member'}
{/case}

{case default="Yes"}
    {redirect='template_name/welcome'}
{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: When the user first logs in they need to agree to Terms and Conditions (accounts are made by the system so the user cant agree to these at registration).

So I need to check if they've agreed to the T&Cs and redirect them accordingly straight after log in.

Comment: Ok, did you look at the source? Copy, rename to make your own plugin and just add a query in the session_start method to check if previously agreed to T&C

Comment: I decided use a different method but thank you for your help.

Comment: Another solution to consider has been added